# CSS text field difference between chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

With the following css style

```
    .form-signin input[type="text"],
    .form-signin input[type="password"] {
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 20px 9px 20px;
    }
```

What I see on the firefox is different from chrome. It seems that the bottom padding in the text field are set different. Look that `g` is not correctly displayed on firefox. How can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle to reproduce the problem.

Comment: See this https://pastebin.com/ux01c2KD

Comment: Have you tried using webkit for firefox? Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance)

Comment: This helped me in a similar case: box-sizing: content-box; or can you update the HTML code in question.

Comment: show your link please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a line-height problem.

Try:

```
.form-signin input[type="text"],
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 20px 9px 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
}
```

24px or more or less

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 potential problems:

1. **The text-box height IS too small**
   Most likely, you have just set the height of the textbox to be too small - you have it as 10px but your font size is 20px.
2. **line-height *might* also be too small** 
   Line-height doesn't appear to be the issue here as I don't see any evidence of it being explicitly set.

When dealing with fonts, its better to use **relative units of measure** such as em or rem. They are **scalable** as they are calculated relative to the size of the font, so it will set the line-height to suit e.g.

```
.form-signin input[type="text"],
.form-signin input[type="password"] {
    font-size: 20px;
    height: 1.25em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    [rest of your css here...]
}
```